# Why can't I say 'I almost don't sleep?

Tags: adverbs, negation, do-support

Why can't I say 'I almost don't sleep? Is there any rule about it?

Comment: Who says you can't say that?

Comment: native speaker said

Comment: Perhaps he thought your intended meaning didn't match what the sentence meant in context. It doesn't sound quite right if you are talking about whether you are sleeping at that particular time. I.e. "Yes, you *are* waking me up, but it's OK; *I almost don't sleep*." Would not sound right in English.

Comment: @LorelC.-- Your comment would be a useful addition to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can say, "I almost don't sleep." In an ongoing situation where sleep is very difficult for a period of time, it means you get very little sleep during that period. E.g.:

> "I have always been a light sleeper, but now that I am in medical
>   school, I almost don't sleep."

It sounds fine to me.

Comment: In principle you *could* use ***almost don't sleep*** in contexts like your example. But in practice I suggest almost no-one ever would - they'd use some variant of ***hardly [ever] sleep [at all]***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: @Jasper: I dunno. As it stands, I have no idea whether OP (or indeed, Lorel above) are thinking in terms of ***almost not sleep*** meaning *sleep incredibly **lightly*** or *sleep **very rarely / briefly***. If the former, there *might* be a case for claiming that the extremely unusual phrasing justifiably reflects an extremely unusual *meaning* (if spoken by a competent native speaker; it would be completely pointless to assume *unusual phrasing = unusual meaning* coming from a non-native speaker).

Comment: On reflection, I've decided to downvote this answer, because I think "It sounds fine to me" is misleading, to say the least.

Comment: A similar sentiment and more 'natural' would be "I have always been a light sleeper... but now I *get almost no* sleep" which I think is more what was intended by your context of 'medical school' (i.e. that you don't get the opportunity to sleep because of long hours, on-call shifts etc). Btw in this case the 'sleep' changes from a verb to a noun.

Comment: Thanks, my context was I don’t need much sleep each night

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's ungrammatical, but it's not a natural way to say anything for a native speaker. "I almost don't" wouldn't be a construction you see very often.

"I barely" would be fine, and "I almost didn't" would also be fine (they mean different things from one another), but "I almost don't" is just not something you see. So, "I barely sleep" means that, in general, one sleeps very little. "I almost didn't sleep" means that, on one occasion or perhaps over a period of time, one came close to not sleeping.

Comment: I barely don't sleep is correct?

Comment: No, "I barely sleep". I'll edit to clarify.